# How to dynamically set RadioButton size in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, radio-button

I want to show **10** `radioButtons` in a **horizontal**.
I've tried to add it in `RadioGroup`, but after running the application, it doesn't show all the `radioButtons`.
 
**My UI image :** 
[image: My Img]

On some devices not all of `radioButtons` are shown.

How can I **dynamically** set size to `radioButton` from devices **screen width** ?

**My layout:**

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bidStepper_txt"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

How can i this?

Comment: Better use `HorizontalScrollView` .. Because if you try to wrap in fix width `RadioButtons`  can be too small of sometimes too large ..

Comment: @ADM, Yes my friend, HorizontalScrollView is better way. but us designer say's not scroll this `RadioButton`s . just fix size for all devices ! can you help me for this?

Comment: try setting layout_weight in radio button i.e android:layout_weight = 0.1

Answer (score 2):

All items shown on screen using give `android:layout_weight=".1"` to all `RadioButton`.

`android:layout_weight` divide the all radio buttons width  in equal size according to width of device screen, but there is an issue in layout because in some devices it can be clipped, because some device has less width of screen, to overcome this you can use the horizontal scroll view like below:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="5" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />

            <RadioButton

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code that will helpful

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.radiobuttonhorizontal_android_examples.com.MainActivity" >



     <RadioGroup
     android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
     <RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Android" />

     <RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="PHP" />

     <RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Blogger" />
    </RadioGroup>

     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/radiogroup"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
     android:text="Horizontal Radio Buttons"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks dear, but i can show horizontal radioButton! but my radioButtons has 10 item and for this not show all of items